# Redirección utilizando JQuery

Tags: jquery, redirección

> De la pregunta del SO original [How to redirect to another page in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/503093/1468942)

¿Cómo puedo redireccionar de una página a otra utilizando [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)?

Comment: asociación: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-do-i-redirect-to-another-webpage

Comment: @fedorqui es el mismo link que tengo puesto al inicio de la pregunta, si no me equivoco? #llibertat

Comment: Miquel: sí, es que todo esto viene [del chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49042217#49042217) porque parece que finalmente tendremos implementado [Preguntas con enlaces cruzados: identifiquemos las ya existentes en este sitio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1320/83). Es decir, cuando alguien con el navegador en castellano entre en _How to redirect to another page in jQuery?_ el sistema le indicará que existe esta pregunta en SOes. ¡Un saludo crack!

Comment: @MiquelColl :D sigues por aqui

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> De la respuesta del SO original [One does not simply redirect using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/506004/1468942)

### Uno no redirige simplemente usando jQuery

jQuery no es necesario, y **`window.location.replace (...)`** es la mejor opción para simular una redirección HTTP.

Es mejor que el uso de `window.location.href =`, porque `replace()` no guarda la página de origen en el historial de la sesión, lo que significa que el usuario no va a quedar atrapado en un interminable fiasco de *botón atrás*.

Si quieres simular que alguien hace clic en un enlace, usa `location.href`.

Si quieres simular una redirección HTTP, usa `location.replace`.

**Por ejemplo:**

```
//Comportamiento similar como una redirección HTTP
window.location.replace ("http://es.stackoverflow.com");

//Comportamiento similar como hacer clic en un enlace
window.location.href = "http://es.stackoverflow.com";
```

---

> De la respuesta del SO original [Using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1638449/1468942)

Esta respuesta utiliza jQuery puro para realizar lo que se pide.

> **ATENCIÓN:** Esta respuesta simplemente se ha proporcionado como una posible solución; obviamente **no** es la mejor solución, ya que requiere jQuery. En lugar de ello, utilizen la solución de JavaScript puro.

```js
$(location).attr('href', 'http://stackoverflow.com')
```