# Guardar id de una imagen clickeada en asp.net (Web Forms)

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Disculpen, alguno me puede ayudar con lo siguiente?
Lenguaje: ASP Web Forms, se maneja c# no PHP.
 Como se podria guardar el id de una imagen al momento de cliclearla?...

Quiero realizar una pagina para una biblioteca, al momento de dar click a la imagen del libro, me redireccione a otra pagina donde me pueda mostrar la informacion del libro, ya tengo el inicio que muestra los libros con su respectivo id, quiero guardar los datos del libro clickeado para mostrarlos despues en la pagina de la informacion del libro, No se como enviar la informacion de la imagen clickeada a la otra pagina.
Porfavor, ayuda :c

Comment: Hola Alan y bienvenido! Te recomiendo leer el [recorrido](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y enseñarnos la parte importante del código :). Aún así lo que comentas es fácil de hacer con jQuery. Ahora te propongo una solución.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo mejor seria que metieras las imágenes de los libros dentro de links y cada uno de ellos redirigiese a la pagina del libro ya con el ID en la url:

```
<a href="libro.aspx?ID=3"><img src='imagenlibro.jpg'/></a>
```

Luego con `Request.QueryString["ID"]` capturas el ID desde la pagina libro.aspx.

Comment: Buena solución con HTML puro :)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes realizar una redirección utilizando jQuery de manera fácil. Tal y cómo explico en [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/20804/7242).

Defines un elemento HTML cualquiera con un `onClick` definido tal que así:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Texto" OnClick="Redirige"></asp:Button>
```

Y definimos la función `Redirige`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" lang="javascript">
   function Redirige() {
       window.location.href = "http://es.stackoverflow.com";
   }
</script>
```

A partir de aquí ya lo tienes.